# XMLSerializer class throwing "array must no be null" exception when compiled in Visual Studio 2017 and .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, exception, visual-studio-2017

I have old code written using VS2008 which I transfered to VS2017. Code was using .NET 2.0 
If I build it using VS2017 and .NET 2.0 I get an "Array cannot be null." in the XMLSerializer constructor 
If I use VS2015 and .NET 2.0 the code is working. With VS2017 it only works if I switch to .NET 4.0 or higher. With VS2015 it is working with all .NET versions.

The call stack on exception looks like this:

```
at System.Reflection.Assembly.nLoadImage(...
at System.Reflection.Assembly.Load(...
at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromFileBatch(...
at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.FromSourceBatch(...
at Microsoft.CSharp.CSharpCodeGenerator.System.CodeDom.Compiler.ICodeCompiler.CompileAssemblyFromSourceBatch(...
at System.CodeDom.Compiler.CodeDomProvider.CompileAssemblyFromSource(...
at System.Xml.Serialization.Compiler.Compile(...
at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateAssembly(...at System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(...
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.GenerateTempAssembly(...
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type, String defaultNamespace)
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer..ctor(Type type)
at XMLSerializerTestVS2017.Form1.button1_Click(....
```

I was able to reproduce the problem with just a few lines of code.

```
Exception pops up on the line 

XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(MyData));
```

And I have defined the MyData class like this (just for testing)

```
[XmlRoot(ElementName = "root")]
public class MyData
{
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MY_XML_A_ENTITY")]
    public string A { get; set; }
    [XmlAttribute(AttributeName = "xml_b_attrtibute")]
    public string B { get; set; }
    [XmlElement(ElementName = "MY_XML_C_ENTITY")]
    public int C { get; set; }
}
```

Does anybody has an idea what could be the reason for this behaviour. The code compiles without problems. Why VS2017 with .NET 3.5 or older is not working on this simple example? I also tried to switch the VS2017 to use C# version 3.0 for compilationa but it made no difference. VS2015 and older (I have tried them out 2013, 2010 & 2008) are all working fine with any .NET version.

Any input is more than welcome! Thx!

**REMARK:**
I am not sure if this is the proper way to handle this, I didn't want to answer my own question because others came with ideas that explained the possible cause for my problem so I I though it would be unapropriate to take the credit for the answer. It seems that something is wrong with my machine (Thx Jack!). Testing the code built with VS2017 and .NET2.0 or 3.5 worked just fine in a fresh VMWare. So I guess there is something wrong on my machine causing the trouble. I still do not know what exactly it is, but if I find out I'll post here. 
Thank you all for help!

**REMARK No. 2**
It seems it is not just my computer. Even though the compiled test code worked in a fresh VMWare, the exception showed again as I run the test code on a machine belonging to a colleague developer. Currently I am inclined to beleive that the problem has to do with VS2017.

**REMARK No. 3**
I did some more testing on other machines on our site. I have tried machines without Visual Studio 2017. The error popped up on those machines to. I am not sure what to conclude from that, but it seems that the combination of compiling with Visual Studio 2017 and running on machines with all the Microsoft updates on it somehow creates the described problem.

Comment: The were changes in default properties when going from Net 3.5 to Net 4.0.  For example SMTP credentials in 4.0 you had to use a credential in 4.0 while 3.5 did not require a credential.  Also Net 4.0 supported 64 bit because it came out a the same time as Windows 7.  By the way there was two version of Windows 7 (32 bit initially and then 64 bit).  Make sure you do a clean build if moving from different versions of Net.

Comment: I have built my test project from scratch in both VS2015 and VS2017 and built it. VS2015 works fine with any .NET (2.0, 3.0, 3.5, 4.0 etc.), VS2017 only with .NET 4.0 or higher. This is what I do not understand, what does VS2017 does differently from older studios?

Comment: And the problem shows in runtime. Compilaion goes just fine also on VS2017. No warnings, no nothing.

Comment: Not sure why you are getting a reflection exception.  Debugging Xml Serialization is tough.  Usually I have to comment out classes or class properties until it works to isolate issue. To figure out the cause.

Comment: This might be a framework issue and not a compiler issue. By default .NET 2 applications will activate on the .NET 2 runtime if it's installed, but they can be configured to use the .NET 4 runtime through the `app.config` (`<supportedRuntime>`). Check if VS 2017 isn't adding something there to make the 2.0 code run as 4.0 (which is not quite the same thing as running code targeting 4.0 on 4.0). Also, try testing your compiled binaries on a completely different system (preferably a fresh VM) to see if something got corrupted on yours (easy if you have a lot of devenvs installed).

Comment: Also, if `<supportedRuntime>` is not actually present you might want to add it, since otherwise "the version of the runtime used to build the application is used", which may well be different for VS 2017.

Comment: The csproj is a text file that you can open with notepad to check the compiler options.

Comment: Is the xml file valid?  I think you are missing a namespace.  Try validating the xml using VS menu : Project : Add New Item : Xml File.  Then paste xml file into view.  Error will show up in the Error List like any compiler error.  I suspect a prefix is not defined in the file.  Your small sample did you test in VS2015?

Comment: @JureJuric, I tested the code in vs2017(.net 3.5 and .net 3.0). I didn't reproduce the problem you provided. Therefore, I think your vs2017 may miss something. I recommend that reinstall the vs2017.

Comment: Thank you Jack for trying it out. It seems all is working fine in a fresh VMWare. There must be something messed up on my machine. I have checked the config files, they are the same with VS2015 and VS2017.  Thank you all for the ideas and effort. Best regards!